# Полупрозрачный слой на все окно сайта

Tags: jquery

Нужно заслонить все окно сайта полупрозрачным слоем, который будет включаться, когда появится окно с каким-либо сообщением. Старый скрипт делает при загрузке окна так

```
$("#fuzz").css("height", $(document).height());
```

Но дело в том, что у меня на 2-страницах есть динамически расширяющиеся области (это график и визуальный редактор), вот там он и дает сбой. Искал что-то вроде **jquery bind document.body.clientWidth** но не нашел. Английский stackoverflow не решил эту проблему. Подскажите решение, а я пока ограничусь 10-секундным

```
window.SetInterval -> $("#fuzz").css("height", $(document).height());
```

все понимают, что это не выход, ведь будут расходоваться дорогоценные ресурсы компютера и обновление вовремя может не наступить.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
body,html { height:100%; min-height:100%; }
.shadow { width:100%; height:100%; position: fixed; top:0px;left:0px; background-color: black; opacity: 0.55; filter: alpha(opacity=55); display: none; z-index:1000; }
```

Попап окну поставьте z-index:1001; При появлении окна:

```
$('.shadow').fadeIn();
```

Если ничего не накосячили при верстке, должно тянуться по высоте

Answer (score 0):

Может это поможет - [jQuery Dialog](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2009/95.html)

Comment: Нет. Я ОТКАЗАЛСЯ от jquery UI - на днях даже оформил все в плагин. А ставить КУЧУ UI ради такого не буду. Рыться в их коде тоже. Нужно какое-то чёткое решение на пару строк кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // javascript
    function showloader(param)
    {
        if ( param=='hide' ) {
             $('overlayer').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
             $('overlayer').style.display = '';

        }
    }

    //css
    .overlayer{
        background-color: #000000;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        visibility: visible; opacity: 0.8;
    }

     //пример
    <div id="overlayer"><a onclick="showloader(hide)">выключить</a></div>

   <a onclick="showloader(show)">включить</a>
```

[пример работы](http://podbordomenov.ru/)

Comment: Попробую. Но вы все попутали. $('overlayer') - где точка(.) или рашпиль(#)? Если уж id="overlayer", то в CSS #overlayer{, а в JS $('#overlayer') !

Comment: Да, пардон. Насчет "все попутали" вы чуток погорячились.

Comment: Забыл добавить, сокращения вида $('overlayer').style.display это от jquery, замените на document.getElementById('overlayer').style.display - как то так.